Issue with exchange backups via veritas netbackup client
I have single on-prem Exchange 2019 installed on win2k22 with 5 mailbox databases.
We're using netbackup version 10 server to backup databases/logs and client 9 on OS
Since Monday evertything correctly, now during exchange full backup or differential incremental we're getting error on the master server ,
Nov 14, 2024 1:30:05 PM - begin writing
Nov 14, 2024 1:30:22 PM - Error bpbrm (pid=1546320) from client exchange01: ERR - Terminating backup.
**Nov 14, 2024 1:30:22 PM - Error bpbrm (pid=1546320) from client exchange01: ERR - failure reading file: Microsoft Information Store:\DB02\Logs_1731587341 (BEDS 0x0: )**
Nov 14, 2024 1:30:22 PM - Error bptm (pid=1546848) system call failed - Connection reset by peer (at ../child.c.1373)
Nov 14, 2024 1:30:22 PM - Error bptm (pid=1546848) unable to perform read from client socket, connection may have been broken
Nov 14, 2024 1:30:22 PM - Error bptm (pid=1546786) media manager terminated by parent process
Nov 14, 2024 1:30:22 PM - Error bpbrm (pid=1546320) could not send server status message to client

On the exchange client side (in the bpfis file) we're getting status as below right before  an error shows in the master server (activity monitor -> jobs )
13:29:41.707 [27284.21008] <2> stop_keep_alive_thread: INF - Stop keep_alive thread
13:29:43.708 [27284.21008] <4> get_backup_status: INF - Create Named Pipe successful for VSS Backup Complete.
13:30:21.976 [27284.21008] <4> get_backup_status: INF - Connect Named Pipe successful for VSS Backup Complete.
**13:30:21.977 [27284.21008] <4> get_backup_status: INF - Message received on named pipe - DB_status:EX_DB 4 DB02:EX_SRVR 11 exchange01:EX_STATUS 13.**
13:30:21.977 [27284.21008] <2> onlfi_vfms_logf: INF - INF - vss__update_db_backup_health: Received backup status - 13 for <DB02> from server exchange01.
13:30:21.977 [27284.21008] <2> onlfi_vfms_logf: INF - INF - vss__update_db_backup_health: Found <DB02> in the backup status list.

In the bpbkar file we see other error
13:30:21.965 [26628.6884] <2> exchange_shadowcopy_access::V_Read_Metadata_Header(): INF - StreamInfo: Id:STAN, FSAttrib:0x0, TFAttrib:0x0, CAlgor:0x61, Flags:0x0, Size:1048576
13:30:21.968 [26628.6884] <2> exchange_shadowcopy_access::V_Read_FI_File(): INF - backup of 'E00002673BE.log' is complete, 1048576 bytes read
13:30:21.969 [26628.6884] <2> exchange_shadowcopy_access::_createMetadataString(): INF - Exchange metadata - '5 1 PfI 2097154 128 133 C:\Program Files\Veritas\NetBackup\online_util\fi_cntl\bpfis.fim.exchange01_1731587341.1.0.MIS_SG1_Logs_E00002673BE.log.MetaData.txt 75 /\\?/GLOBALROOT/Device/HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy12/DB02_LOGS/E00002673BE.log'
**13:30:21.969 [26628.6884] <2> exchange_shadowcopy_access::V_Read_Metadata_Header(): ERR - invalid STRM header, ID is 0x4145544e**
13:30:21.969 [26628.6884] <4> tar_base::V_vTarMsgW: INF - tar message received from dos_backup::tfs_readdata
13:30:21.969 [26628.6884] <2> tar_base::V_vTarMsgW: ERR - Terminating backup.

I checked vss writers status on the exchange and all of them are stable and no errors, application logs for any errors , permissions for netbackup client , network and storage system in terms of issues and stability, antivirus but still not luck.
Can you please point out what should be checked and investigated ?

I'm sorry to hear you're experiencing these issues with your Exchange backups.  Here are a few steps you can take to investigate further: Review VSS Writers: Even though you mentioned the VSS writers are stable, it might be worth double-checking their status again. Ensure that the database copies are not corrupt. You can use Exchange tools to check the integrity of the databases.

Finally it turned out that after reinstalling Netbackup client from version 9 to 10.0.0.1 backups started to work again.
